# Convert special character like $ to hexadecimal

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nsstringencoding

I am working on an iOS application. In this application I am trying to convert `NSString` to hexadecimal. But in some cases `NSString` contains special `$, ¥,` etc. This is where I am facing problem. These characters don't convert to hexadecimal.

Is there any way to convert special characters to hexadecimal?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by NSString to Hexadecimal ?

Comment: Search in google "Convert NSString to Hexidecimal value" and find a loads of questions and answers.

Comment: are you currently converting it with a for loop?  How do you do the conversion?

Comment: You should at least show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the string to NSData

```
[NSString dataUsingEncoding:]
```

Then using the data object you can output any base you want: octal, hex, decimal, binary.

Comment: Why do you need to convert it to `NSData` to do that?